# Finding the mean difference of two data sets in R, within a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, mean

I'm analysing benchmark data for some of my R functions, and I'm trying to compute a statistic describing how many times faster my function - group_one - is than a control function - group_two -  as a multiplier (group_one is $\alpha$ times faster than group_two).

The data are assumed to be normally distributed, of equal length. The variance is assumed to be different between groups.

```
test_data <- list(
    group_one = c(9387298, 9447571, 10343495, 10232936, 10296492, 10273234, 16732716, 10527317, 10675171, 9434651)
    group_two = c(23721104, 39465146, 31087543, 39851996, 38027882, 44277978, 32448261, 39950612, 47677503, 38887976)

# how many times smaller is the mean of the first group than the second?
multiplier <- mean(test_data$group_one) / mean(test_data$group_two)
```

The variance of the the benchmark data is typically about 15% of the mean, so I'm trying to find a 95% confidence interval in which the multiplier lies (something of the form "group_one is 10 - 12 times faster than group_two")

Does anyone know an R function (preferably in the base library) that could be used to compute this interval?

@COOLSerdash:

I tried t.test, but it doesn't directly give an confidence interval in which the population mean lies, and I don't know how to infer that interval based on the t test.

@Peter Flom: I added more realistic data above; the initial "data" were just random numbers. I can see that the ratio of the two distributions might be too sensitive to usefully gauge how much faster group_one is compared to group_two; if an alternative statistic would be more useful I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What about `t.test` with `var.equal = FALSE`? That computes the mean difference of two variables.

Comment: I am confused. What is assumed to be normally distributed? Your test data is clearly nowhere close to that. The ratio of two normal distributions is tricky to estimate, but if it is the ratio of two times, then at least both are positive. However, if the times vary a lot (say some tasks are much longer than others) then ratio may not be best. Doubling 1 microseconds is not equivalent to doubling 10 minutes.